# How do I know if the component the user being navigated to has state navigate('/tsaks/updateTask', { state: {task: data})

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that list all the tasks, and if the user click on that task he will be redirected to /tsaks/updateTask along with the data of that task.

```
navigate('/tsaks/updateTask', { state: {task: data})
```

The reason why I want that is to prevent displaying the page directly.

So at the APP.js I want to check if the router have revived state.task and if not redirect him to /tasks

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/tasks/" element={<Header childComponent={<Tasks/>}/>}/>
        <Route path="/tasks/new" element={<Header childComponent={<addNewTask/>}/>}/>
        <Route path="/tasks/updateTask" element={<Header childComponent={<UpdateTask/>}/>}/>
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to achieve the same thing would be to do a check for the data at updateTask component like this

```
let location = useLocation();
const taskData = location.state?.task

if (!taskData)
   return <Navigate replace to={'/tasks'} />

...
// rest of your code
```